# How to pass complex type using httpClient with DeleteAsync?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-delete

I am trying to do a delete to a Web API web service using HTTPClient.

This is simple enough if I simply pass the id of what I need to delete in the uri:

```
deleteAsync("http://localhost/myService/main/deleteItem?id=1234567")
```

but if I want to pass back a complex type on delete, can I pass back that object as json in the body of the request and the access it from the service using [FromBody]? How would I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use httpPost to post your complex object to your delete method.

E.g.

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("Post")]
public HttpResponseMessage DeleteComplexObject(Models.ComplexObject deleteme)
{
    this.ComplexObjectService.Delete(deleteme);
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);

    return response;
}
```

Here model binding is used to convert your json object into the ComplexObject automatically so you don't need to use [FromBody]